# Make localization for burn bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, wix, burn

I have burn bootstrapper and ui for it in CustomUi.dll. I add Resources.resx for default culture and Resource.ln.resx for other language. I use it from xaml like this:

```
 xmlns:res="clr-namespace:CustomUi.Properties"
 x:Static res:Resources.Break_Installation
```

But when I execute Bootstrapper.exe not in the default language, i get default localization. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this! It was necessary to add this string `<Payload Name="de\CustomUi.resources.dll" SourceFile="Lib\de\CustomUi.resources.dll"/>` to bundle.wxs